# When to close SummaryWriter when I'm conducting many deep learning experiments

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm changing models, optimizers etc. I want to be able to compare the results. So, when should I close SummaryWriter?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do exactly, but it is preferable to use 'close' after every time you write something, e.g. add_scalars, add_text.... Consider also using "flush"

Comment: Hi @othmanmarfoq, I was wondering if you could give me some references. I didn't find a detailed guideline for tensorboard.

Comment: This (tutorial)[https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html] is good if you are using torch, and this (one)[https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started] is good if you are using tf. Both of them covers basic stuffs, e.g. adding scalars, images... If you want to do something beyond you will need to read the documentation

Comment: Thank you I'm using pytorch. I read that tutorial before. But it's not in depth so I'm still in need of more material.

Comment: There are also some good examples in this [repo](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX)